# How to use facebook client token in a native mobile client

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Could some one show me example or explain how to use Facebook client token in a native mobile client to make Graph API requests?

Comment: Which programming language you are using?

Comment: @Musakkhir Sayyed I'm using Java

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408778/how-to-re-authenticate-native-desktop-facebook-app) may help you.

Comment: @Musakkhir Sayyed Unfortunately not, it's about re-authenticate app but not using of app client token

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/android:

> The Places Graph SDK automatically selects the access token when a new request is created. If a user access token is available, it will be used; otherwise, the client token is used.
>
> The following code example demonstrates how to set the Client Token.

```
// Get your client token from the developer portal.
String CLIENT_TOKEN = "{your_client_token}";

FacebookSdk.setClientToken(CLIENT_TOKEN);
// At this point, requests on PlaceManager can be invoked. 
// Users do not have to log in Facebook.
```